# Is there a better way to index this array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

We were given the code;

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.transpose(np.diag(np.arange(2,8)) + 10*np.ones((1,6)) - np.arange(10, 4, -1))
*_____*=np.eye(2)
```

and asked to fill in the *_____* so that the array printed is;

```py
[[ 2.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  4.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 2.  2.  6.  2.  2.  2.]
 [ 1.  3.  3.  0.  3.  3.]
 [ 4.  4.  4.  4. 10.  4.]
 [ 0.  5.  5.  1.  5. 12.]]
```

I tried putting the following in;

```py
a[3,[0,3]],a[5,[0,3]]
```

which when I put this into python gave me the correct array, but when I filled it into the website it told me it was incorrect.

I am wondering if there is a neater, or more efficient way to index the array as that might be the intended solution.

Thank you, any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the result you want with:

```
a[3::2, ::3] = np.eye(2)
```

See:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.transpose(np.diag(np.arange(2, 8)) + 10*np.ones((1, 6)) - np.arange(10, 4, -1))
a[3::2, ::3] = np.eye(2)
print(a)
# [[ 2.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
#  [ 1.  4.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
#  [ 2.  2.  6.  2.  2.  2.]
#  [ 1.  3.  3.  0.  3.  3.]
#  [ 4.  4.  4.  4. 10.  4.]
#  [ 0.  5.  5.  1.  5. 12.]]
```